# How to rotate images saved in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, images, image-manipulation

On a regular basis I take pictures with my Android phone and upload them to Google drive. Sometimes I take the picture upside down and want to rotate it. In Google Drive how do you do this? I found [these instructions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/141914?hl=en) but they don't make any sense, maybe I'm in the wrong mode or something but I don't see any "rotate handle".

Out of curriousity I've noticed some programs open images upside down and others do it right side up? For example I've downloaded one of the pictures from Google Drive and when I opened it locally with my computer it was right side up.

UPDATE 2017: it would appear google drive now has this option built in for photos.

Comment: There are any number of image editors available for Android, some even owned by Google. Why not use one of those?

Comment: @ale which one is own by google?

Comment: @JinSnow [Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed).

Comment: @ale thanks but I meant using googgle drive on PC (snapseed is only available on android, it doesnt' show on the google drive app "open with")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a native way: access [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/).

[First you need to enable google drive pictures as shown here.](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) Please once in that page, read below "View & edit photos stored in Google Drive using Google Photos"

Then select the image, and either press shift+r, or in the top right corner choose "more options"> Rotate

Edit: Please note, according to [this official help page:](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

> If you edit photos in Google Photos, those changes will not show in
>   Google Drive.

That means you have to manually move the edited photos in google photos to the desired goal location, such as google drive.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly Google Drive natively [cannot](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DsXcJoGX-sM) rotate images. Some programs try to reorient the image when you open it, which explains your second paragraph.

The guide you linked to refers to the Google Drive application [Google Drawings](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/mkaakpdehdafacodkgkpghoibnmamcme?hl=en-US). After [installing it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/mkaakpdehdafacodkgkpghoibnmamcme?hl=en-US), you can create a Drawing document:

[image]

in which you can rotate images:

[image]

Comment: What is the guide I linked to talking about?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sentence, answer edited.

Comment: There is indeed a native way, as in my answer, but depends what you understand as "native".

Answer (score 0):

If you have Google drive app/folder downloaded to your device you can turn the images on your device and when the folders sync it will update the rotation for all of your images.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to print on chrome, and then rotate:

[image]